# Chrome not loading stylesheet for nearly identical pages

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet

http://azlro.org/chad/1991rrchunter.html loads correct, with black background image in Chrome and Explorer. The code:

```
`<html>
<head>
<title>My advice to other 1987 to 1995 Range Rover Classic Owners</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-TrainTunnel.css">
<meta name="author" content="Chad Manz">
<meta name="keywords" content="chad manz, range rover, range rovers, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, County, Great Divide Edition, GDE, Hunter, SWB, LWB, land rover, land rovers, upgrade, upgrades, modification, modifications, tips, advice, recommendation, recommendations">
<base target="_blank">
</head>
<body>
<p>
<center>
<br>
<table width="875">
<tr>
<td>`
```

http://azlro.org/chad/rrcadvice.html does not load the stylesheet in Chrome and thus has a white background instead of the black background image above. However, it will load the black background image and follow the stylesheet in Explorer, with the same stylesheet being used for both links. The code:

```
`<html>
<head>
<title>My advice to other 1987 to 1995 Range Rover Classic Owners</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-TrainTunnel.css">
<meta name="author" content="Chad Manz">
<meta name="keywords" content="chad manz, range rover, range rovers, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, County, Great Divide Edition, GDE, Hunter, SWB, LWB, land rover, land rovers, upgrade, upgrades, modification, modifications, tips, advice, recommendation, recommendations">
<base target="_blank">
</head>
<body>
<p>
<center>
<br>
<table width="875">
<tr>
<td>`
```

This has been driving me nuts for months.

Is there something I'm not seeing that I need to correct in the code for the second link?

Comment: same problem in Firefox actually. For whatever reason, when i open the developper tools, the CSS file is loaded, but the content is full of chinese characters(?)

Comment: The page with white background has a console error. Something with google analytics. You may have to fix that first.

Comment: Looks like your system doesn’t specify the used character encodings anywhere, but simply lets the client “guess” instead. While that works fine for UTF-8, your second document seems to be stored in `utf-16le` instead, see https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fazlro.org%2Fchad%2Frrcadvice.html

Comment: Yes. According to Page Info, the second HTML page is UTF-16LE and the stylesheet is windows-1252, same as the first HTML page. Fix that and you're done. By the way, if you're fixing things anyway, both pages use Quirks Mode. Put a proper DOCTYPE on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second Page is [UTF-16](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Transformation_Format) Encoded therefore the wrong characters in the Stylesheet.
What you need is [UTF-8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Transformation_Format)

Start your html Document properly like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
.
.
.
```

> The `<!DOCTYPE html>` should ensure that Quirks Mode is **not** used.

Dont forget to close `<html>` and `<head>` tags (No need to close the "DOCTYPE" Tag.

Comment: Thank you! I made those changes...

    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">`

...and made other minor corrections and removed the Google tracking code.

When I create/edit/save my files I used Notepad. Should I be using a better program to create/edit/save my html files that saves them correctly in the same UTF?

Comment: I also figured out how to have as UTF-8 using Notepad.

Comment: For Coding Front-End Stuff like HTML, CSS, JS i am using Visual Studio Code which is an IDE that offers alot of customization and addons. You can also use www.codepen.io to experiment with your Code and Share with others. If my Answer resolved the Problem the Question is about mark it as Correct so others know the Post is closed :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Greatly appreciated.